# Getting exception while updating table in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have created one table in hive from existing s3 file as follows:

```
 create table reconTable (
 entryid string,
 run_date string
 )
 LOCATION 's3://abhishek_data/dump1';
```

Now I would like to update one entry as follows:

```
update reconTable set entryid='7.24E-13' where entryid='7.24E-14';
```

But I am getting following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.
```

I have gone through a few posts here, but not getting any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an `external` table when reading data from a source like `S3`.

Also, you should declare the table in ORC format and set properties  `'transactional'='true'`.

Please refer to this for more info: [attempt-to-do-update-or-delete-using-transaction-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198339/attempt-to-do-update-or-delete-using-transaction-manager-that-does-not-support-t)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this Cloudera Community Thread:

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-update-delete-and-insert-ERROR-in-cdh-5-4-2/td-p/29485

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.